# Ruby ArgumentError trapping

Tags: ruby

Given a class:

```
class Foo 
  def initialize(input1) 
    @input1 = input1 
  end 
end
```

is there some way that would throw a more helpful error against `a = Foo.new()`? How can I build a method that throws an `ArgumentError` in a more helpful way?

I'd like to build this into the class. The [Programming Ruby site](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) lists several error-trapping mechanisms, but all of these seem to depend on wrapping `a = Foo.new()` in a `catch` block or the like. I would like to have my error trapping within the class itself however.

Comment: What is a "more helpful error"? Your question is vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a default value and raise whatever error you need within the initialize method for example

```
Class A
  def initialize(a = nil) 
    raise("give me an A") if a.nil? 
    @a = a
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're new to Ruby it's understandable this error might seem odd, yet it's also an error that's very specific to passing the wrong arguments in. Remapping it to something else isn't necessarily helpful, it ends up hiding problems in your code. I'd suggest leaving it as-is and expecting errors like that to occur if you're not calling it correctly.

The alternative is, at least in newer versions of Ruby, to declare keyword arguments with no defaults:

```
def initialize(input1:)
end
```

That's a required keyword argument, and the error is more specific:

> ArgumentError: missing keyword: input1

The downside is you have to call it like this:

```
Foo.new(input1: 'test')
```

That might be beneficial in terms of clarity. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty simply by raising that error when the argument is not defined. You can add a message to the `ArgumentError` exception by specifying it as an argument on the exception:

```
class Foo 
  def initialize(input1=nil)
    raise ArgumentError, "expected a value for Foo.new('value')" unless input1
    @input1 = input1 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Isn't the default ArgumentError raised before the ArgumentError within initialize?

Comment: Good point. Default the argument to nil, and then raise the argument error inside the initialize block. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) a bit more, I think using [alias_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) as a hook might serve:

```
alias_method :initialize_orig, :initialize
def initialize(*args)
  begin
    result = initialize_orig(*args)
    return result
  rescue Exception
    $stderr.print "Need to use argument 'input1'\n"
    raise
  end
end
```